# How to merge two xml by using xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, sorting, xpath, xmlstarlet

I want to sort xml elements numerically, but failed at the last step(to merge two xml).
This is what I have tried:

#### content of xml file

```
$ cat input.xml
<root>
    <title>hello, world</title>
    <items>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </items>
</root>
```

#### sort items

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -R -t -m '//item' -s A:N:- 'number(.)' -c '.' -n input.xml
<xsl-select>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</xsl-select>
```

#### delete items

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//item' input.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <title>hello, world</title>
  <items/>
</root>
```

#### how to merge the outputs? the result should be:

```
<root>
    <title>hello, world</title>
    <items>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked but nevertheless. Following shell
script produces the wanted result using a multi-stage pipeline --
though it's hardly the best way to process a larger input.
For an approach using [XInclude](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) with `xmlstarlet` see
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76035373/14403369) answer.

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh
xmlstarlet select -R -t -m '//item' -s 'A:N:-' '.' -c '.' input.xml |
xmlstarlet select -R -t -c '/ | document("-")' input.xml |
xmlstarlet edit \
  -d '/xsl-select/root//item' \
  -m '/xsl-select/xsl-select/item' '/xsl-select/root/items' |
xmlstarlet select -B -I -t -c '/xsl-select/*[1]'
```

1. run `select` to extract a sorted file of `item`s (to `stdout`)
2. run `select` to copy the original input and the sorted file and
   (`-R`) wrap them together, using the XSLT
   [`document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document) function to access
   the sorted file on `stdin` (output from this step is listed below)
3. invoke `edit` to delete the unsorted `item`s and move the sorted
   `item`s in place
4. run `select` to extract and format the merged document

Output (indented) from step 2:

```xml
<xsl-select>
  <root>
    <title>hello, world</title>
    <items>
      <item>2</item>
      <item>1</item>
      <item>3</item>
    </items>
  </root>
  <xsl-select>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
  </xsl-select>
</xsl-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with xmlstarlet, but for what I saw in its documentation it can be used to apply an XSL transformation to a XML file (`tr`) - you can use that command with this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to generate the sorted and merged output in a single operation.

Comment: The answer does resolve the problem described, maybe without using xml starlet, but it does not answer the original question: I have two xml files that I like to merge, so creating a single transform is not possible.