# Use XMLStarlet to insert a single value too long to fit on a command line

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

Suppose I have an xml file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="a"></string>
</map>
```

And I want to set the value of *string* with attribute *a* with something big:

```sh
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '/map/string[@name="a"]' -v $(for ((i=0;i<200000;i++)); do echo -n a; done) example.xml > o.xml
```

This will result in bash error  "Argument list is too long".  I was unable to find option in xmlstarlet which accept result from a file.  So, how would I set the value of xml tag with  200KB data+?

**Solution**

After trying to feed chunks into the xmlstarlet by argument -a *(append)*, I realized that I am having additional difficulties like escape of special characters and the *order* in which xmlstarlet accepts these chunks.
Eventually I reverted to simpler tools like xml2/sed/2xml.  I am dropping the code as a separate post below.

Comment: If you want a hack, set it to some string which you are sure that does not exist in the xml (e.g. `THIS_STRING_DOES_NOT_EXIST`) and then replace `THIS_STRING_DOES_NOT_EXIST` with your intended string using sed or similar tools.`

Comment: @anishsane  I am just trying to find a legit way to edit xml.

Comment: You could use the -a option of xmlstarlet (append) instead of -v, cut down your command say to 20000 instead of 200000, and loop 10 times over that.  So you would append 20000 each loop.

Comment: @Roadowl interesting proposal.  I would not call it a legit way though. :)

Comment: @Roadowl any suggestions how I can do that in bash?  I tried to use a combination of xargs, read, echo and cut .... unsuccessfully.  Lets assume that we are working with real world data, not just a string of 'a'

Comment: @Roadowl what do you mean by "instead of -v"?  It seems that -a must be used in conjunction with it.  Can you provide POC of your proposal?

Comment: Heh. I asked this same question and answered it myself some years back...

Comment: @reardenlife "Lets assume that we are working with real world data" effectively makes this a new question, with new conditions and new criteria. No fair!

Comment: ...that said, 200KB is simply *too long* for many operating systems -- there's an OS-enforced limit on the amount of data that can be in (combined) environment variable and command-line space.

Comment: @reardenlife, ...which is to say that you may need to reach for different tools, to insert a single huge element rather than a large number of smaller ones. Might I suggest the excellent XML libraries Python ships with?

Comment: @reardenlife, ...to be clear: This isn't a bash error; it's an operating-system error; the `execve()` syscall fails when it's passed content that can't be fit in the relevant memory region, no matter what the invoking language is.

Comment: For anyone trying to add *many* new elements, as opposed to *a single long* element, see the near-duplicate [handling long edit lists in xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898939/handling-long-edit-lists-in-xmlstarlet).

Comment: I ended up using xml2/2xml and sed.  :)

Comment: @reardenlife, ...why not add your own answer showing how you did that? It'd likely be useful to other readers.

Comment: @Charles Duffy. Done. But I doubt it would be useful for anyone. :)

Comment: @Cyrus but there is simply no decent solution to be accepted.  So what's the point of voting or accepting then?

Answer (score 0):

This, as a workaround for your own example that bombs because of the ARG_MAX limit:

```
#!/bin/bash
# (remove 'echo' commands and quotes around '>' characters when it looks good)

echo xmlstarlet ed -u '/map/string[@name="a"]' -v '' example.xml '>' o.xml

for ((i = 0; i < 100; i++))
do
    echo xmlstarlet ed -u '/map/string[@name="a"]' -a -v $(for ((i=0;i<2000;i++)); do echo -n a; done) example.xml '>>' o.xml
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I am not proud of it, but at least it works.

```
a.xml - what was proposed as an example in the starting post
source.txt - what has to be inserted into a.xml as xml tag
b.xml - output
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ixml="a.xml"
oxml="b.xml"
s="source.txt"
echo "$ixml --> $oxml"

t="$ixml.xml2"
t2="$ixml.xml2.edited"
t3="$ixml.2xml"

# Convert xml into simple string representation
cat "$ixml" | xml2 > "$t"

# Get the string number of xml tag of interest, increment it by one and delete everything after it
# For this to work, the tag of interest should be at the very end of xml file
cat "$t" | grep -n -E 'string.*name=.*a' | cut -f1 -d: | xargs -I{} echo "{}+1" | bc | xargs -I{} sed '{},$d' "$t" > "$t2"
# Rebuild the deleted end of the xml2-file with the escaped content of s-file and convert everything back to xml
# * The apostrophe escape is necessary for apk xml files
sed "s:':\\\':g" "$s" | sed -e 's:^:/map/string=:' >> "$t2"
cat "$t2" | 2xml > "$t3"
# Make xml more readable
xmllint --pretty 1 --encode utf-8 "$t3" > "$oxml"

# Delete temporary files
rm -f "$t"
rm -f "$t2"
rm -f "$t3"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of merging XML and XML or XML and text. This can be
done by having [`xmlstarlet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)'s `transform` command
perform [XInclude](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) processing.
Merging XML and XML can optionally be done with its `select` and `edit`
commands (combine-extract method).

These 2 data files are used in the following:

- `file1.xml` - the main file to which stuff is added:
  `<map><string name="a"></string></map>`
- `file2.xml` - the part file from which stuff is copied:
  `<doc><g><g1/><g2/><g3/><g4/></g></doc>`

---

First, the XInclude method:

```sh
# shellcheck  shell=sh  disable=SC2016,SC2064
mainfile='file1.xml'
partfile='file2.xml'
mainxpath='/map/string[@name="a"]'
partxpath='/doc/g/*'

mainftmp="$(mktemp)"
partftmp="$(mktemp)"
trap "rm -f -- '${mainftmp}' '${partftmp}'" INT EXIT
cp -- "${partfile}" "${partftmp}"

xmlstarlet edit \
  -s "${mainxpath}" -t 'elem' -n 'xi:include' \
  --var V '$xstar:prev' \
  -s '$V' -t 'attr' -n 'xmlns:xi' -v 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude' \
  -s '$V' -t 'attr' -n 'href' -v "${partftmp}" \
  -s '$V' -t 'attr' -n 'xpointer' -v "xpointer(${partxpath})" \
"${mainfile}" > "${mainftmp}"
xmlstarlet select -C -t -c / |
xmlstarlet transform --xinclude /dev/stdin "${mainftmp}"
```

where:

- the `mainxpath` shell variable holds the XPath expression which
  points within the main file, i.e. the destination XML element to
  add stuff to, and `partxpath` specifies the nodes to extract from
  the part file
- `mktemp` creates absolute pathnames for temporary files,
  `trap` deletes them after use
- `xmlstarlet edit` is invoked to modify the main file:

  - the 4 `-s` (aka `--subnode`) add an [`xi:include`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#include_element)
    element to the destination element:
    `<xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="/path/to/partftmp" xpointer="xpointer(/doc/g/*)"/>`
  - the XPointer expression specifies the XPath of the nodes to include
    from the part file, it's possible to use complex expressions here
    such as [unions](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#NT-UnionExpr)
  - `--var` defines a named variable, and the back reference `prev` (aka
    `xstar:prev`) variable refers to the node(s) created by the most
    recent `-s`, `-i`, or `-a` option which all define or redefine it
    (see [`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt) for examples of
    `--var` and `$prev`)
- `xi:include` elements may appear in both the main file and XML part file(s)
- `xmlstarlet transform --xinclude` does the XInclude processing using
  an XSLT stylesheet (generated on the fly by `xmlstarlet select`)
  which duplicates its input by copying the root node `/`

Output:

```xml
<map>
  <string name="a">
    <g1/><g2/><g3/><g4/>
  </string>
</map>
```

Merging XML and text: if the 4th `-s` action (`xpointer="…"`) in the
`edit` command above is replaced with
`-s '$V' -t 'attr' -n 'parse' -v 'text'`
the entire part file is parsed as text and the special XML
characters automatically escaped, generating the following output:

```xml
<map>
  <string name="a">
    &lt;doc&gt;&lt;g&gt;&lt;g1/&gt;&lt;g2/&gt;&lt;g3/&gt;&lt;g4/&gt;&lt;/g&gt;&lt;/doc&gt;
  </string>
</map>
```

---

Second, the combine-extract method:

```sh
# shellcheck  shell=sh  disable=SC2016
mainfile='file1.xml'
partfile='file2.xml'
mainxpath='/map/string[@name="a"]'
partxpath='/doc/g/*'

xmlstarlet select -R -t \
  --var part -o "${partfile}" -b \
  -c ' / | document($part)' "${mainfile}" |
xmlstarlet edit -m '/xsl-select'"${partxpath}" '/xsl-select'"${mainxpath:-/..}" |
xmlstarlet select -B -I -t -c '/xsl-select/*[1]'
```

- invoke `select` to copy the 2 documents and wrap them (`-R`) as
  `/xsl-select/*[1]` and `/xsl-select/*[2]`, using the XSLT
  [`document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document)
  function to access the part file – either the main file or the part
  file can be `/dev/stdin`
- call `edit` to move grandchildren of `${partfile}`’s root element to
  `${mainxpath}` – incoming nodes will be appended as last nodes there
- the default `${mainxpath}` value (`/..`) causes an error to be
  generated and must be overridden
- invoke `select` to extract and format the merged document

Output:

```xml
<map>
  <string name="a">
    <g1/>
    <g2/>
    <g3/>
    <g4/>
  </string>
</map>
```

---

Lastly, if 200000 "a"s are in fact required the [EXSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exslt)
[`str:padding`](https://exslt.github.io/str/functions/padding/index.html) function is useful for character
repetition:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  --var T 'str:padding(100000,"a")' \
  -u 'map/string[@name="a"]' -x 'concat($T,$T)' \
file1.xml
```

Note that
[`libexslt`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxslt/-/blob/master/libexslt/strings.c#L377)
(not EXSLT) limits the length of `str:padding` output to 100000 (one
hundred thousand).